# Drawing a Circle With JavaScript, Only Getting a Sliver

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am going through the book *Pro HTML5 Games* 2nd Edition, and am on the first chapter and am running into an issue. The `full circle` is supposed to be inside of the `half-circle` the problem though is that I am only seeing displayed a sliver of the `full circle`. See screenshot: [image: only getting sliver]

I have tried adjusting the x and y points, as well as the start angle, but to no avail, I just get the same sliver of circle. 
What am I doing wrong here?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        // This function will be called once the page loads completely
        function pageloaded(){
            // Get a handle to the canvas object
            var canvas = document.getElementById("testcanvas");

            // Get the 2d context for this canvas
            var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

            // Drawing arcs & circles
            // draw a semi-circle
            context.beginPath();
            // Draw an arc at (400, 50) with radius 40 from 0 to 180 degrees, anti-clockwise
            // PI radians = 180 degrees
            context.arc(100, 300, 40, 0, Math.PI, true);
            context.stroke();
            context.closePath();

            // Draw a full circle
            context.beginPath();
            // Draw an arc at (500, 50) with radius 30 from 0 to 360 degrees, anti-clockwise
            // 2 * PI radians = 360 Degrees
            context.arc(100, 300, 30, 2 * Math.PI, true);
            context.fill();
            context.closePath();

            // Draw a three-quarter arc
            context.beginPath();
            // Draw an arc at (400, 100) with radius 25 from 0 to 270 degrees, clockwise
            // (3 / 2 * PI radians = 270 degrees)
            context.arc(200, 300, 25, 0, 3 / 2 * Math.PI, false);
            context.stroke();
            context.closePath();

        };
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are missing the start angle here:

```
context.arc(100, 300, 30, 2 * Math.PI, true);
```

Correct:

```
                          | that was missing
context.arc(100, 300, 30, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
```

Comment: yep that was it. Thank you very much.